# Unknown animal - What could it be?

Tags: zoology, species-identification, embryology, animal-models

It's the first time I use this website and I really need help
because I'm totally stuck

Now I'm in school, but I'm trying to prepare for the Olympics
During the preparation, I found the issue on the anatomy of the animals, but it's something new for me - I can't even determine what it is!

[image]

What kind of animal is it? Could you determine some, the most vital and major of highlighted points? If you can help me to determine the kind of it, i will be able to use more specific books to find out.

I will be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Click on edit and insert in your edit all the terms for the numbers.

Comment: @SANBIsamples - that's part of the question, it's homework

Comment: okay @AliceD what's unhappy with homework?

Comment: @SANBIsamples, there's nothing that's unhappy, but by the looks of it you asked for clarification, but OP asks to have the numbers explained. In other words, you re-asked the question.

Comment: @AliceD I consider your homework question closed.

Comment: I have no idea what animal this is, perhaps a mussel?

Comment: Assuming you mean the Biology Olympiad, I would hazard a guess that this is a deshelled snail, judging from the visible helix in the middle and right images.

Comment: This looks like a very specific picture taken from a lab or lecture notes. Unless you were in the lab or lecture, or have access to the notes, it will be tough. Comments above suggested snail and mussel, which were also my first two ideas but it's really too tough to tell.

Comment: or a turtle fetus?

Answer (score 3):

The animal is very suggestive for [Dog whelk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_whelk)-like [mollusc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollusca) removed from its shell.

I try to mark the organs, do not rely on these marks as an absolut.

1. Testis
2. Renal vein
3. Gill
4. Mantle
5. Prostate
6. [Osphradium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osphradium)

10 and others - digestive and reproductive systems, cannot mark precisely.

16. Digestive gland

[source for comparing etc](https://www.flickr.com/photos/56388191@N08/14697629780/in/photostream/)